# dynamically adding a tab, on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html code :

```
<div id="container-1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2">List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3">List</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">one</div>
    <div id="fragment-2">two</div>
    <div id="fragment-3">three</div>
</div>
<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>
```

and I want to add one more tab "fragment-4" which is on button onclick event.
this tab div is out of `<div id="container-1">`. and I am use following java script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tabs = $("#container-1").tabs();
            var tabCounter = 1;

        $('#add_tab').click( function(){
            var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
            $( "<li><a href='#fragment-4'>Call Detials</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            tabs.tabs('select', 1);
        });
  });
```

Using this function I can get dynamically tab but not content which is write in this tab.
so please suggest me what can I do?

Comment: you need to add the content div also `$( '<div id="fragment-4">four</div>' ).appendTo( tabs );` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdKp5/1/

Comment: You can use appendTo('#container-1') to add a div with the ID #fragment-4. If you want to load content, you can add a hidden div to your code or load the content with a Ajax-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/UXuWt/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabs = $("#container-1").tabs();
    var tabCounter = 1;

    $('#add_tab').click( function(){
        var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
        var current_idx = ul.find("li").length + 1; // Get correct index for id
        $("<li><a href='#fragment-" + current_idx + "'>Call Details</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
        tabs.append( $('#callDetail') );
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabs.tabs("select", 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: mishik,I saw your demo but my content of div is one big form with some operation so how can I get that contents in div.

Comment: Once you have added new tab you can change the contents of `$("#fragment-4")` via append() or html() methods.

Comment: but,how can I add html form through append() or html() ?

Comment: `form` is also a tag you can do: `your_elem.html("<form><input type='submit' value='submit me' /></form>");`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the `li` you need to add a `div` with the content. The ID of the div should match the `href` attribute of the `li` element.

Something like this:

**EDIT**: Added dynamic tab ID's

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabs = $("#container-1").tabs();
    var tabCounter = 3;

    $('#add_tab').click(function () {
        tabCounter++;

        var ul = tabs.find("ul");
        $('<li><a href="#fragment-' + tabCounter + '">Call Detials</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
        tabs.append('<div id="fragment-' + tabCounter + '">Hello there ' + tabCounter + '</div>');
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabs.tabs('select', 1);
    });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2uWnz/1)**

Comment: That's because you get several elements with the same ID's, it would be easy to add a counter to make all ID's unique, but that wasn't specified in the original question

Comment: @mishik It's a good suggestion though, and the OP did have a variable called "tabCounter" which could be intended for making unique ID's, so I updated my answer to use dynamic ID's. You can now add as many tabs as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with adding the `li` you need to add a content div also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabs = $("#container-1").tabs();
    var tabCounter = tabs.find('ul').first().children().length;

    $('#add_tab').click( function(){
        var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
        $( '<li><a href="#fragment-' + ++tabCounter + '">Call Detials</a></li>' ).appendTo( ul );
        $( '<div id="fragment-' + tabCounter + '">'+ tabCounter +'</div>' ).appendTo( tabs );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        tabs.tabs('select', tabCounter - 1);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdKp5/)

Comment: I want to add html form in dynamic tab contents, not a one or two words so,please suggest me different way?

Comment: @AloNE how is the dynamic contents created, is it loaded from the server

Comment: @AloNE how is it generated

Comment: Hi Can you please check this question and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948703/tab-content-shows-one-below-another. I need to add dynamic tab contents inside tab. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tabs       = $("#container-1").tabs();
    $('#add_tab').click( function(){

        var tabCounter = $('#container-1 ul li').length; // return number of tabs

        // add tabs with button
        $('#container-1').append("<div id='fragment-"+tabCounter+">Content</div>");
        $('#container-1 ul').append("<li><a href='#fragment-"+tabCounter+">"+tabCounter+"</a></li>"); 
        // Note : if you want show literal number, use something like .replace() 

        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabs.tabs('select', tabCounter);
    });
});
```